# Mouseout() jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Добрый день.

Пытаюсь сделать на jquery что-то вроде меню. Когда навожу курсор на ссылки меню закрывается(оно и понятно). Как этого избежать? Для того, чтобы открыть "меню" наведите курсор в левый верхний угол

```
$("#menu").hide();
$("#openmenu").on("mouseover",function(){
$("#menu").show("drop",{direction:"left"}, "slow");
$("#openmenu").hide();
});

$("#menu").on("mouseout", function(){ 
$(this).hide("drop",{direction:"left"},"slow");
$("#openmenu").show("slide",1500);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pic0/Yscpn/18/

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[РЕШЕНО]
http://jsfiddle.net/pic0/7VgcP/2/
Использовался .hover()

Answer (score 0):

Проверяйте куда ушел фокус

http://jsfiddle.net/Yscpn/19/

if ($(e.toElement).parents().index($menu)>=0 || e.toElement===this) return;

$menu заранее задано...

но лучше такое на css делать, гораздо всё проще.